# Need to get cetegory in non English

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I did this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
WHERE { 
    [ rdfs:label ?name ;
      dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract
      dcterms:subject ?categoryUri ] .
    ?categoryUri rdfs:label ?categoryName .
    FILTER langMatches(lang(?abstract), "ar").
    FILTER langMatches(lang(?name), "ar")
}
LIMIT 100
```

But it always show the sub category in English and i need it in Arabic.

Comment: [Standard SPARQL `SELECT` queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#select) do *not* use commas to separate projected variables after the `SELECT`.

Comment: OK but still same problem. ?categoryName is always in English. I need it in Arabic.

Comment: Yes, I pointed out the syntax issue so future visitors are not misguided into thinking they are looking at correct syntax (at least, once it is fixed in the question). I have added [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30095530/1430156) to suggest how to solve the question.

Comment: So i use *? or what is the correct way?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?abstract ?categoryName` should do.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your query do you restrict the subcategory name to be in Arabic. There are two language-related restrictions, namely:

```
FILTER langMatches(lang(?abstract), "ar") .
FILTER langMatches(lang(?name), "ar") .
```

As you can see by the arguments to the [`lang` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-lang), these restrict the language of `?abstract` and `?name`, respectively.

Be aware that these restrict *only* the labels you are retrieving. The `?categoryUri` resource whose IRI you are retrieving is still just the "complete" resource from the dataset, *not* filtered or scoped in any way by language. Hence, it might contain labels in many languages, for instance in English.

If you want to also restrict `?categoryName`, you will have to add an appropriate additional filter:

```
FILTER langMatches(lang(?categoryName), "ar") .
```

Comment: @Taha: Then maybe there are no category names available in Arabic?

Comment: @Taha: That gives me four results, which are linked to a number of categories, none of which has an Arabic label. As I said, there seem to be no category names available in Arabic.

Comment: Add this: VALUES ?name { "برج إيفل"@ar } . It has categories in Arabic. http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%AC_%D8%A5%D9%8A%D9%81%D9%84